# Deleted FAVICON from themes folder is showing up

Tags: 7

**I have deleted the favicon.ico from the themes folder.**

**But its still showing up the same favicon**. I totally confused.

**Steps I have taken:** But nothing works... :-(

1. Checked whether I am in the right directory.
2. Cleared browsers cache.
3. Cleared Drupal Cache.
4. Use the default shortcut icon is checked. (No custom favicon selected)
5. favicon is located in the sites/all/themes/theme_name/favicon.ico

Could you guys please advice me is there any other way to check or resolve.

Any help will be thankful and grateful...

Comment: which theme using?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/touch...

Comment: show the html source pls - is something defined in .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Its corrected...

**On Themes Global Settings I have mentioned the same favicon in differnet folder.**

Thats why the deleted favicon dispalyed even after deleting it from the themes folder.

Thanks for your efforts friends...